# How to deploy gnosis safe contracts on multichain

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, gnosis, gnosis-safe

I am trying to fork gnosis safe react and contract repository. I have successfully set up gnosis safe react and contracts locally. I just want to know that how can I deploy its contracts by using my metamask wallet.
I have run yarn deploy-all rinkeby then It is showing reusing instead of deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your mnemonic address and infura key in your contract app. Maybe you can add one little function in order to be sure it is your deployed contract.
You should also provide etherscan API to watch your deployment on etherscan. Even if you deploy your contracts to your address you could not see them on safe-react app because it fetches contracts from gnosis/safe-deployments app and gnosis deployed addresses kept in there. You can fork that repo to your own and add your deployed address for each contract. Publish your repo to npm and use your deployed contract from safe-react app by npm install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added my mnemonic address, infura key and etherscan API key in the contract app .env file. When I have run **yarn deploy-all rinkeby** then It is not deploying instead of this It is showing reusing word with contract address which was already deployed.

`$ yarn deploy-all rinkeby
yarn run v1.22.15
$ hardhat deploy-contracts --network rinkeby
Nothing to compile
reusing "SimulateTxAccessor" at 0xaA35F6e1A161410e21bDaC2553B7A87Ea9574e4f`

Comment: Can we schedule meeting over google meeting or talk over skype? Please. Thanks in advance

https://join.skype.com/invite/omvHDlC35uSi

Comment: skype link on so?